# See function signature where pointer points to

Tags: c#, pointers, dll, unmanaged, kernel32

I am making calls to an unmanaged dll. The way I do so is like:

```
    // Kernel functions used to load dll
    #region Kernell 32

    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string lpFileName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    #endregion

    public void Test()
    {            
        IntPtr dllHandle = LoadLibrary(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\SEGGER\JLinkARM_SDK_V484c\JLinkARM.dll");

        // here is a function that enables me to read data from a chip
        var ptr = GetProcAddress(loadedDllHandle, @"JLINK_HSS_Read");
        {
            Delegate1 readMem = (Delegate1)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(Delegate1));

            // then if I want to read an integer from memory address 0x100 I will do
            byte[] dataToRead = new byte[4];
            unsafe
            {
                fixed (byte* fixedPointer = dataToRead)
                {                        
                    // <----- FIRST CALL TO DLL WORKS GREAT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                    var retn = readMem(0x100, 4, (IntPtr)fixedPointer);  
                }
            }
        }


        // there is another function called JLINK_HSS_Start
        ptr = GetProcAddress(loadedDllHandle, @"JLINK_HSS_Start");
        {
            Delegate2 x = (Delegate2)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(Delegate1));                              
            unsafe
            {
                var m = x(5); // here I get an exception!
            }
        }

    }
```

THE EXCEPTION THAT I GET SAYS:

> Additional information: A call to PInvoke function
>   'Jlink!Jlink.HighSpeedSampling.Hss+JLINK_HSS_Start_Handler::Invoke'
>   has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke
>   signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that
>   the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match
>   the target unmanaged signature.

**The first function call works the second one does not**

**In other words I cannot call x(5). Probably because I need to pass more parameters.** I do not know the signature of that method. How can I find out the signature of the method. The pointer is not null so I know the function exists. If I type the method name incorrectly I get a null pointer. One solution is to type different signatures until it does not crash. There could be so many combinations. **So in short I know that the pointer is pointing to a function. How can I know the signature of that function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look in the header file that comes with the SDK. One thing to watch out for is the calling convention. You may need to add `[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]` to your delegate deceleration, not doing so when required will cause this exact error (as will getting the parameters wrong).

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your second call:

```
Delegate2 x = (Delegate2)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(ptr, typeof(Delegate1));
```

You're passing the type of Delegate1 and then cast to Delegate2.